# Open vim to a specific line with a variable

Tags: vim

I'm trying to do the following:

```
vim +$line $LEDGER
```

But instead of opening at the line number it's opening two files, one the number and the other the actual file I want to open.

Comment: It works for me (bash on Mac OS X).  Are you sure that `$line` and `$LEDGER` are defined?  `$ echo $line $LEDGER`.

Comment: It could be that that `$line` has leading whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, there is leading whitespace before the number in `$line`. There are several ways to fix this:

#### proper quoting

```
$ vim "+$line" "$LEDGER"
```

Note that it's always a good practice to quote variables, even if they currently don't contain whitespace or other problematic characters.

#### remove whitespace

```
$ vim +${line# } "$LEDGER"
```

Comment: I was doing `wc -l $LEDGER` and didn't realize it was adding the filename onto the output. I switch to `wc -l $LEDGER | awk '{print $1}`

Comment: Ah! You could also use `cat $LEDGER | wc -l`, or `${line% *}`.